# How to fix JPopupMenu get hidden inside the insets of the border?

Tags: java, swing

I need to show a menu inside a dialog. However when the JPopupMenu gets hidden inside the border when the barder insets are large.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;
import java.awt.*;

public class PopupMenuBorderInsetsBug {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JDialog popupDialog = new JDialog();
        popupDialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        popupDialog.getRootPane().setBorder(new BorderWithInsets(Color.RED));

        JButton btnShowMenu = new JButton("Show Menu");

        JPopupMenu menu = new JPopupMenu();
        menu.add(new JMenuItem("Menu Item"));

        btnShowMenu.addActionListener(e -> menu.show(btnShowMenu, 0, btnShowMenu.getHeight()));
        popupDialog.add(btnShowMenu);

        popupDialog.pack();
        popupDialog.setVisible(true);
    }

    private static class BorderWithInsets extends LineBorder {
        public BorderWithInsets(Color color) {
            super(color);
        }

        @Override
        public Insets getBorderInsets(Component c) {
            return new Insets(10, 10, 30, 10);
        }
    }
}
```

Above code creates a dialog box and when clicked on the button menu should appear but it get hidden inside the border inset.
[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D11dQ.png)

If the insets of the border is changed as this `return new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10);`, menu shows without any problem.
[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vCvDK.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is due to the wrong use of root panes, you must put the components in the JDialog's contentPane.

See the changes in `main`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JDialog popupDialog = new JDialog();
    popupDialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

    //Use a JPanel as container and set insets and content on it
    JPanel content=new JPanel();
    content.setBorder(new BorderWithInsets(Color.RED));

    JButton btnShowMenu = new JButton("Show Menu");

    JPopupMenu menu = new JPopupMenu();
    menu.add(new JMenuItem("Menu Item"));

    btnShowMenu.addActionListener(e -> menu.show(btnShowMenu, 0, btnShowMenu.getHeight()));
    
    content.add(btnShowMenu);

    //Set the panel as contentPane for the dialog
    popupDialog.setContentPane(content);
    popupDialog.pack();
    popupDialog.setVisible(true);
}
```